# Efficient Way to use LIKE in an SQL join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the query below, which seems to work but is far too slow to use. Can anyone recommend a way to make this more efficient?

```sql
SELECT NLPostedNominalTran.TransactionDate
      ,NLPostedNominalTran.GoodsValueInDocumentCurrency
      ,NLPostedNominalTran.Reference
      ,NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative
      ,SOPOrderReturn.DocumentNo
      ,NLPostedNominalTran.OpLock
      ,NLPostedNominalTran.DateTimeCreated
  FROM NLPostedNominalTran
  LEFT JOIN SOPOrderReturn ON NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative LIKE CONCAT('%', SOPOrderReturn.DocumentNo, '%')
```

Basically what needs to happen is it needs to show the DocumentNo value from SOPOrderReturn if a valid document number is present in the NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative column.

EDIT: I cannot manipulate the way the data in this table is processed as it is part of an ERP system that I cannot change.

Comment: For a leading wildcard, there isn't one; such a clause is non-SARGable, meaning the *entire* index/table must be scanned. Seems like the real problem is that a column like `Narrative` needs to be used in an `ON` clause, and that the `DocumentNo` should be a separate column in the table as `NLPostedNominalTran` as well.

Comment: That's for MySQL, @MatBailie .

Comment: @MatBailie this link talks about full text search indexes and specialized functions, not LIKE. SQL Server also has full-text search indexes. FTS indexes accelerate searching for words though, not arbitrary patterns

Comment: Is `NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative` free text or can it be processed to find document number(s) automatically?

Comment: @Arvo it is free text

Comment: Is document number separate word or can it be part of longer word? If it is separate, then again some speedup is possible (split text to words and join documents to words - or use full-text search).